# CSS border covering the whole page instead of the element only

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my border rule in CSS. I'm using a style sheet in Visual Studio Code to decorate my HTML page. I have been trying to creat a border around the 'div' elements, but it's adding a border around the whole page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRlR4.png)
Could someone please advice me on how to place a border around the 'div' element only, not the whole page.

TIA.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FYax.png)

I've tried adding the rule directly to the element as opposed to the .css style sheet but it is still not formatting correctly.

Comment: Welcome to [so] - please take the [tour] and read the [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  For starters, you can include a [mre] of the issue in the question for faster troubleshooting - btw, it's nearly impossible to debug images of code ;)

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's because your giving border to all Divs in the document:

```
div{
    border: 2px solid crimson;
}
```

try giving ids or classes to your HTML elements and then give them styles:

```css
.container {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#div_1 {
  border-color: crimson;
}

#div_2 {
  border-color: green;
}

/* Notice: always use ids and classes when you have more than one of the same tag (like: div)*/
```

```html
<div>
  <div id='div_1' class='container'>This is the first div!</div>
  <br>
  <div id='div_2' class='container'>This is the second div!</div>
</div>
```

I hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Assign class name to div on which you wanted to apply border on and then apply border property to that div with class ,by simply div it give border to all div element ,